# How to serializable/parcelable Pair in Andorid Studios

Tags: java, android

I am trying to start a new Activity from main, the new activity requires NO information from the previous activity however it will send something back to the main activity, but that I have yet to implement. 
Now what I find really weird is that my main used to work like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maintemp);
    ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //Add stuff to the array
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("list", list);
    FooFragment fooFrag = new FooFragment();
    fooFrag.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.foo_fragment, fooFrag)
            .commit();

}
```

And this works as intended.
Now I wanted to potential start an activity if some conditions where met

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maintemp);
    if(/*Some conditions*/){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Bar.class));
    }
    ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //Add stuff to the array
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("list", list);
    FooFragment fooFrag = new FooFragment();
    fooFrag.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.foo_fragment, fooFrag)
            .commit();

}
```

When I meet the if criteria and the Bar activity starts, the IDE/Compiler complained that:

> Parcel: unable to marshal value Pair

Now the Activity doesn't need the Pair list at all, but somehow it complains that it wasn't Parcelable

To fix this I tried to make a class containing only the Pair list and make the class serializable and just bundle the class
this gave the error

> Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Which I think is again due to not being able to serialize the pair.

So is there a way to make Android's Pair Parcelable? or is my error else where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is there a way to make Android's Pair Parcelable?

you can't. you can either pass the information separately in the bundle (first and second) or create your own `Pair` class that implements `Parcelable`

Comment: Do you know why I can bundle it to my fragment view, but that no longer works when I start a new activity?

Answer (score 0):

Use `HasMap` instead it has key value pair as well and can be pass between activity with Serializable or Parcelable for saving the item order use `LinkedHashMap`